# How to clear objects form eden space JAVA8?

Tags: java, memory-leaks, jvm

I want the memory to be stable, with no interference from the “Garbage Collector” and no exceed in memory usage as well.

```
package com.company;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;
import java.net.URI;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GetThread().start();
    }

    static class GetThread extends Thread {

        private HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();
        private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

        public GetThread() {

            this.httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .build();

            try{
                httpGet.setURI(new URI("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp"));
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            StringBuilder body;

            for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
            {
                try{
                    CloseableHttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                    body  = new StringBuilder(EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity()));

                    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
                    response.close();

                    body.setLength(0);

                    response = null;
                    body = null;
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }


    }
}
```

Problematic line

body = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());

I tried to set this object as null but it still exists in the Eden space.

[Yourkit graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Co3rl.png)

[Memory dump](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sBNk3.png)

Although the object is null, it still exists in the memory until the “Garbage Collector” cleans the memory.

Thanks!

Comment: You should not be doing this.  Let the GC do its job. I'd recommend looking for a JVM for real time apps that have dealt with GC accordingly.

Comment: Objects cannot be null. Variables can store the value `null`. The heap is cleared on garbage collection cycles. Why do you expect or want anything different?

Comment: Sounds like an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/) question. You should make a question (infused with actionable data!) about the actual GC issue you're trying to solve.

Answer (score 0):

You can't remove object from Eden, only GC can do it.
Setting reference to `null` won't clear the space occupied by the object.

Comment: So, the solution is to limit the eden space size?

Comment: Why limit eden space? What are you trying to do? There is very limited number of cases where you want to be gc-free. Why you want it here? You will be gc-free if you won't create new objects and none of libraries that you create will create them.

Comment: When GC is running the program freezes for 1-3 seconds each time.
what can i do to prevent from object to keep alive in eden space? Thank you

Comment: Eden GC takes usually less then 500ms, what you see is probably full GC which takes place mostly in the old space.

Answer (score 0):

The only way to avoid both garbage collection and increased (heap) memory usage is to not allocate new objects on the heap.

In Java when memory is allocated, used for a period of time and then no longer referenced, the garbage collector is the mechanism that recovers the memory and makes it available for reuse. If you create objects and then stop referencing them, they will continue to consume that portion of the heap until the garbage collector runs.

It is just the way that Java is designed to work.

Answer (score 0):

Solution, Reuse in objects&Don't create string objects

```
package com.company;

import org.apache.http.client.methods.CloseableHttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.CloseableHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.HttpClientBuilder;
import org.apache.http.util.EntityUtils;

import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.io.Reader;
import java.net.URI;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        new GetThread().start();
    }

    static class GetThread extends Thread {

        private HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet();

        private final CloseableHttpClient httpClient;
        private CloseableHttpResponse response;

        private StringBuilder content = new StringBuilder();
        private char[] buffer = new char[1024];


        public GetThread() {

            this.httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create()
                    .build();

            try{
                httpGet.setURI(new URI("https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.whatsapp"));
            }
            catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        @Override
        public void run()
        {
            Reader in;
            int rsz;

            for (int i = 0; i < 50000; i++)
            {
                content.setLength(0);

                try{
                    response = httpClient.execute(httpGet);

                    InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();

                    in = new InputStreamReader(is, "UTF-8");

                    for (;;)
                    {
                        rsz = in.read(buffer, 0, buffer.length);

                        if (rsz < 0)
                            break;

                        content.append(buffer, 0, rsz);
                    }

                    in.close();

                    EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());
                    response.close();
                }
                catch (Exception e){
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

This code much better than the first code, profiling results
[Mmeory graphs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5BGoL.png)

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MNBip.png)

Comment: You are now reading and dropping the data slightly more efficient, but considering that the entire operation is obsolete, as you are not using the data, it’s still insanely inefficient. Perhaps, the line `EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity());` does something, but that’s the only one (and it doesn’t receive the data you have read. So everything besides `response = httpClient.execute(httpGet); EntityUtils.consume(response.getEntity()); response.close();` can be removed. Or in terms of your original code posted in the question, you could have just removed the problematic line…